# cannot install ubuntu 12.10 when I select boot device

Tags: system-installation

I have created a bootable Ubuntu by using universal USB installer(downloaded from Ubuntu official site). When I select boot device (my pen drive) from boot menu as usual the Ubuntu has appear, after selecting language it gives me four option try on USB, install Ubuntu and another two options I forget it whatever when I select "install Ubuntu" my computer restart and cannot load from USB. I have tried other three options but same result.

I am using windows 8, ram 6gb.

Anybody can help me please? Is there another way to install Ubuntu 12.10 ?

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for ur help bt i'm facing another problem, after installing Ubuntu computer wants to reboot but after rebooting I cannot find any boot option to select operating system, just start my windows8 also the drive where I have installed Ubuntu cannot see. How can I fix it.
Help me pls

Answer (score 0):

use rufushttp://rufus.akeo.ie/

load the iso into it

restart your computer

set your boor preference to USB

install

enjoy!!!